# subversion get latest without updating svn:externals

Tags: svn

svn is slow as it is ( leaving the rant out)
the last thing I think is necesary is to do a request ofr externals is you got latest 5 min ago
any way to get latest without/skipping externals
Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`svn up --ignore-externals`

Skips externals, works on the checkout too.

Comment: in tortoise, use "update to revision" and check "ignore externals" in the dialog.